# Cannot fit bayesian model with rethinking::quap for small (1e-4) parameter values

Tags: r, numerical-methods, bayesian

I'm trying to calculate the posterior for `p` using `rethinking` package version 2.13:

```
rethinking::quap(
  alist(
    n ~ dbinom(N, p),
    p ~ dnorm(1e-4, 0.5e-4)    
  ),
  data = list(n = 10, N = 10e4),
  start = list(p = 10 / 10e4)
)
```

It throws an error:

> Error in rethinking::quap(alist(n ~ dbinom(N, p), p ~ dnorm(1e-04, 5e-05)),  :
> non-finite finite-difference value [1]
> Start values for parameters may be too far from MAP.
> Try better priors or use explicit start values.
> If you sampled random start values, just trying again may work.
> Start values used in this attempt:
> p = 1e-04

`start` is actually the MAP.
It works for bigger `p` values.
How to solve the problem?

Comment: does your version of the package give the same extensive error message that mine does?

Comment: Thanks, I added more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** you're running into numerical approximation problems; adding `control=list(ndeps=1e-6)` to adjust the finite-difference tolerance is the fastest way to solve the problem.

Alternatively, you could change the model to fit `p` on the log scale:

```
alist(
    n ~ dbinom2(N, exp(logp)),
    logp ~ dnorm(-4, 2)
)
```

More generally, if you are working on a problem where `p` might be larger than, say, 0.5, you should probably fit on the log-odds or logit scale rather than the log scale, using `plogis(logit_p)` instead of `exp(log_p)`. (I used log/exp instead of logit (qlogis)/plogis because I thought of it first, and because it's more familiar to most people.)

Two methods I tried that **did not** work (that I thought should have; I would need to dig in further to find out whynot): (1) specify the expected scale of the parameter via `control=list(parscale=1e-4)`; (2) use `method="L-BFGS-B", lower=0` to set a lower bound on the probability parameter.

The sad reality is that the tools for numerical evaluation of likelihoods, posteriors, etc. are fragile enough that you very quickly get to the point where you need to know something about what's going on under the hood.

---

We can diagnose what's going on by writing a `dbinom2()` function that's simply a "noisy" wrapper for `dbinom`:

```r
dbinom2 <- function(x, size, prob, log) {
    r <- dbinom(x, size, prob, log)
    cat(x,size,prob,r,"\n")
    return(r)
}
```

Then re-run the estimation with `dbinom2(...)` in place of `dbinom(...)`, and we get:

```
10 1e+05 1e-04 -2.078512 
10 1e+05 0.0011 -78.1496 
10 1e+05 -9e-04 NaN
```

The `x` and `size` values stay constant in this case; the search algorithm first tries `prob=1e-4`, then `prob=0.0011`, then `prob=-9e-04` (a *negative* probability value), which is where it runs into trouble.

- The error message gives more clues as to what is going on (*if* you already know quite a bit about how things work under the hood); `quap()` is using the "BFGS" method by default (it passes this straight to `optim()`, which means that it is trying to use the *derivatives* or *gradients* of the function to find the MAP estimate.
- Because we don't have an explicit expression for the gradients, R does the next best thing (which is pretty crappy, but works OK for simple problems), which is to try to estimate the gradients by *finite differences* — basically replicating the definition of the derivative as `lim(dx→0) (f(x+dx)-f(x))/dx`, but using a small ("finite") `dx` value rather than trying to take the limit.
- the problem arises in deciding on `dx`. Going **way** down into the help page for `optim()` (`?optim()`), you can see:

> ‘ndeps’ A vector of step sizes for the finite-difference
> approximation to the gradient, on ‘par/parscale’ scale.
> Defaults to ‘1e-3’.

This means that `optim()` is using `dx=0.001`, which is where your problem comes from. It tries `f(x-dx)` as well as `f(x+dx)`, and since `x-dx` is <0, this breaks the calculation.  Using `ndeps=1e-6` specifies that `dx` should be smaller (small enough so that `optim()` doesn't try to evaluate the log-likelihood for a negative probability).